# Coding loan repayment period formula in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the formula as followed:

n = ln(A/(A-Pi))/ln(1 + i)

Where A=7500  and P= 50000 and i=0.05

I tried to code this in Java with:
when i output this, it states : "NaN"
.kindly advise on how to improve on my code

```
public void loanFormula() {
n = -(Math.log(A/(A - (P * i))) /-(Math.log(1 + i));
{
```

Comment: bascially i tried to output this in my mainclass with : " c.getN()" , with getters and setters already generated.

Comment: How do you set valules for A, P and i? That is not shown...

Comment: And why Minus ("-") before both Math.log?

Comment: You need to set values for the parameters: A/P/i

Answer (score 0):

the output of your expression is not a number.

try the below expression

```
n = (- Math.log(A/(A - (P * i))) /(-Math.log(1 + i));
```